# Keras-based CNN acc stays at around 1/n% while training

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

Code:

```
#Importing the Keras libraries and packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
import keras.optimizers as optimizers

#Initialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

#Convolution Layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (32, 32, 3), activation = 'relu'))

#Max Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

#Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

#Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

# Compiling the CNN
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
classifier.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd, metrics = ['accuracy'])


#Fitting the CNN to the images
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('Oranges/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (32, 32),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('Oranges/test_set',
                                            target_size = (32, 32),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch = 800,
                         epochs = 25,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         validation_steps = 62.5)

classifier.save('my_model.h5')  # creates a HDF5 file 'my_model.h5'
```

The input is about 200 images belonging to 5 classes (vegetables). acc stays at around 18-19% although i let it train through the whole process (800 steps * 30 epochs with a batch size of 32). I tried messing with the optimizer settings(lr, decay), but nothing seems to really work for me. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can try few things.
1) Try to use optimizer like RMSProp/Adam and lr at 0.01/0.001/0.0001
2) Try to use loss function categorical_crossentropy
3) Add BatchNormalization layer after Conv and Dense layer.
4) Use softmax as last layer so that you'll get probability of each class.
5) Run model for around 5 epochs and then if accuracy does not improve than change lr by setting model.optimizer.lr to less value that last one.
6) Also try model once with only Dense Layers.

Comment: tried all of what you said, nothing helped except for the BatchNormalization which at peak settings brought the acc up to 0.22 but it got stuck there. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Did you try reducing hidden layer size? BTW it seems like you have far less data than for example MNIST dataset, so training a model on that might just not work.

Comment: I see you are trying data augmentation through ImageDataGenerator. Try more option and do more data augmentation. Data is very less to train a model though.

Comment: Also if possible give me training data, i can try different models.

Comment: Try the following:
1. Recheck model architecture using classifier.summary()
2. Check if training labels for mixed up somehow (happens)
3. Bring down lr till 1e-6, see if it helps

Comment: Why are you using a single unit in the last layer? I see you have five classes, then you should use 5 units in the last layer with softmax activation. Then use categorical_crossentropy loss. Try adding one more convolutional layer after first layer. As suggested above try more data augmentation techniques.